# How do I improve the accuracy of my supervised document classification model?

Tags: classification, python, text-mining, supervised-learning, multi-class

Given 1000 legal judgement documents, 900 of which are labeled, my task is to predict the label for the remaining 100 documents. The labeled documents belong to 41 different categories of Law, with some classes having only 1 sample each to some having around 80 samples. I adopted an approach similar to one used on a Kaggle competition: https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words

After encountering many errors and fixing it to the best of my abilities, I finished with a very poor accuracy. I'm not very familiar with Python and the object-oriented style of programming, having used MATLAB so far for all Machine Learning related code. My code is shown below. Could anyone kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong or how better to improve the accuracy? Alternate methods too are welcome.

```
    class DataCreation:
        # Read all files into Python Dictionary    
        def read_txtFiles (self , path):
            data = {}
            for dir_entry in os.listdir(path):
                dir_entry_path = os.path.join(path, dir_entry)
                if os.path.isfile(dir_entry_path):
                    with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
                        (prefix, sep, suffix) = dir_entry.rpartition('.')   # Strip away .txt extension from filenames in dict
                        data[prefix] = my_file.read()
            return data

        # Read class labels file into List
        def read_labels(self , csvFile):    
            with open(csvFile, 'rb') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                labels = list (reader)
            return labels

        # Separate Unlabeled Data from the rest of the dictionary
        def separate_data(self , labels , data):  
            # Get filenames of the 'To be Tested' files
            if labels[0][0] == 'Judgements':        
                del labels[0]
            out_sample_labels = []
            for item in range (0 , 100):
                if not labels[item][1] == 'To be Tested':
                    print 'Halt! The filename %s has label %s' %(labels[item][0] , labels[item][1])
            # Shift the unlabeled class labels to a serarate list
            out_sample_labels = labels[0:100]
            del labels[0:100]        
            # Match these filenames to the ones in the dict and store these in a separate dict
            out_sample_data = {}
            for name in out_sample_labels:
                if name[0] in data:
                    out_sample_data[name[0]] = data[name[0]]
                    del data[name[0]]
            return out_sample_labels , out_sample_data

        def split_dataset (self , dictionary , n , labels):
            rand_lst = random.sample (dictionary , n)
            var_dict = {}
            for item in rand_lst:
                if item in dictionary:
                    var_dict[item] = dictionary[item]
                    del dictionary[item]
            var_labels = []
            for obj in labels:
                if obj[0] in var_dict:
                    var_labels.append([obj[0] , obj[1]])
                    labels.remove([obj[0] , obj[1]])
                if not len(var_labels) == len(var_dict):
                    for k in labels:
                        if k[0] in var_dict:
                            var_labels.append([k[0] , k[1]])
                            labels.remove([k[0] , k[1]])
            return var_labels , var_dict

    class PreProcess:

        def process_text (self , raw_text):
            # input is a single string and output is a single string
            # Remove HTML tags
            review_text = BeautifulSoup(raw_text).get_text()    
            # Remove non-letters
            letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]" , " " , review_text)
            # Convert to lowercase, split into individual words
            words = letters_only.lower().split()
            # Convert stopwords to set for faster searching
            stops = set (stopwords.words("english"))
            # Remove stopwords
            meaningful_text = [w for w in words if not w in stops]
            # Join words back with space and return result
            return (" ".join(meaningful_text))

        def feature_extract(self , list_of_strings):
            # CountVectorizer
            vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)        
            tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(list_of_strings)
            return tfidf        

        def sort_dataset (self , labels , dictionary):
            final_set = []        
            for obj in labels:
                if obj[0] in dictionary:
                    final_set.append([obj[0] , obj[1] , dictionary[obj[0]]])                
            return final_set

    class Classify:
        # Module for Classification

        def fit_predict(self , clf , feat_matrix , response , val_feat_matrix):
            # Fit Forest to Training set using bag-of-words as features and
            # sentiment labels as response variable
            model = clf.fit (feat_matrix , response)
            predicted = model.predict(val_feat_matrix)
            return model , predicted

        def metrics (self, response, predicted, category):
            score = metrics.accuracy_score(response, predicted)
            print("accuracy:   %0.3f" % score)
            print("classification report:")
            print(metrics.classification_report(response, predicted,
                                                target_names=category))
            print("confusion matrix:")
            print(metrics.confusion_matrix(response, predicted))
            return score
#########$$$$$$$$$$   CLASSIFIERS  $$$$$$$$$$$$############    
clfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
clfm = MultinomialNB()
clfs = SGDClassifier(alpha = 0.0001 , n_iter = 100 , loss = 'modified_huber')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trialTest = DataCreation()
    dic = trialTest.read_txtFiles (path)
    lbls = trialTest.read_labels(csvFile)
    # Separate the unlabeled data    
    unlbl_lbls , unlbl_data = trialTest.separate_data(lbls , dics)
    training_lbls , training_data = trialTest.split_dataset(dics , 540 , lbls)
    testing_lbls = copy.deepcopy(lbls)
    testing_data = dics.copy()
    trialFE = PreProcess()
    final_training = trialFE.sort_dataset(training_labels , training_set)
    final_testing = trialFE.sort_dataset(testing_labels , testing_set) 

    # Pass training & testing set through the Pre-processor
    clean_training = []
    for obj in final_training:
       clean_training.append(trialFE.process_text(obj[2]))

    clean_testing = []
    for obl in final_testing:
       clean_testing.append(trialFE.process_text(obl[2]))

    # Pass training & testing set through the Feature Extractor
    train_feat_matrix = []
    train_feat_matrix = trialFE.feature_extract(clean_training)
    train_feat_matrix.todense()     
    print train_feat_matrix.shape

     test_feat_matrix = []
     test_feat_matrix = trialFE.feature_extract(clean_testing)
     test_feat_matrix.todense()
     train_response = []
     for ele in final_training:
         train_response.append(ele[1])

     test_response = []
     for elg in final_testing:
         test_response.append(elg[1])

     Tr1_lbls , Tr1_set , Tmp1_dict = trialTest.create_sets(lbls , dictss)
     categories = []
     for atom in Tr1_lbls:
        categories.append(atom[1])
     categories.sort()

     trialClass = Classify()
     # model , prdct_test = trialClass.fit_predict(clfm , train_feat_matrix , train_response , test_feat_matrix)
     # multinomial_metrics = trialClass.metrics(test_response, prdct_test, categories)
```

I was unable to perform feature reduction using PCA as the resulting structure after feature extraction was a sparse matrix and didn't work well with PCA.

Answer (score 1):

Step one: Identify all of the settings in your model that might impact performance. These settings will either involve data transformation (such as min_df in tfidf) of model hyperparameters (such as max_features in your RandomForestClassifier).

Step two: Wrap everything in a pipeline. [Examples](http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html)

Step three: Use RandomizedSearchCV to find an optimum set of parameters. [Example](http://web.stanford.edu/~schwancr/examples/quadwell-n-states.html)

Step four: Use the cross validated errors of the fit RandomizedSearchCV object to estimated the generalized error rate of your model.

Step five: Try different models and data processing strategies.

Step six: Use your model to predict your raw testing data.